# Horizontal or vertical navigation on mobile saas apps?

Tags: navigation, mobile-application

Is there any (new) research on whether to go with horizontal or vertical navigation on mobile-responsive saas apps? I've seen a bunch of articles from 3-5 years ago and was trying to see if anyone had a more recent perspective.

Our situation is below:

1) B2B SaaS Product (web based app like Workday or ZenDesk)

2) Web & Mobile (Hybrid App)

Comment: Need a bit more information - how many items are in the nav? What is it used for?